# Visual Studio 2015 Preview - Can't commit with Git

Tags: git, git-commit, visual-studio-2015

I can't commit my projects from Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

When I press the `Commit` button from the Team Explorer window, I get this error message :

[image]

The last sentence in english : *The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

I couldn't find if any other process actually use the specified file.

In Visual Studio 2013, everything works fine. So actually I'm switching between VS2015 and VS2013 everytime I need to commit some changes made on a project, but it's a real waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same exception. I saw that VS2015 was creating a new folder next to the solution file with a name like: `<solutionname>.sln.ide`. I have no idea what this folder is good for but you should find the mentioned file that is locked by another process there.

Because I didn't want to have new files in my repository as long as I'm working with VS2013, I added the folder path to my .gitignore file. Then I could commit again.

Comment: Indeed.  We strongly recommend either following the prompts in Visual Studio to create a `.gitignore` or to use the one at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Indeed.  We strongly recommend either following the prompts in Visual Studio to create a `.gitignore` or to use the one at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know about the .gitignore file. Adding a default one to my project did the trick ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Frederic I was able to find a nice solution. I'm new to git so I didn't now about the use of .gitignore files.

Simply go into `Team Explorer` -> `Repositories Settings`. Under `Ignore File`, click **Add**.

[image]

This will add a default .gitignore file.

After that I never saw the error message again.